# syntax highlighting for code blocks in answers to general questions

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

A while ago I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707425/463828) answer for moderator attention, because the code example has no syntax highlighting. My flag got declined because - quote from the moderator:

> Unfortunately, not in a way that I'm aware of.

Now I just found out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/213325), that the syntax highlighting depends on the `tags`.

In the case of the question, I wouldn't tag the question with a specific language, because it's a general question, but the answer shows a language-specific example, which should have syntax highlighting for better readability.

Is it possible to enforce syntax highlighting in answers or for code blocks?

Comment: Don't flag, edit it yourself and if you don't know how leave it be, there are more than enough 2K+ users who will gladly edit those things. Flags are not for editing.

Comment: Already done in this case.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well those 2k+ users didn't do it, since I tried and didn't find out how to do it. Also the moderator who saw my flag didn't know how to do it. So the flag wasn't simple for editing, but also to find out if there is a bug...

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' thanks for editing the post. It's much more readable now. Can you give me a hint what you did?

Comment: I checked your edit, but I don't see any `prettify language code` there...

Comment: Added `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` before the code block (no indentation, one empty line above and below) to tell the highlighter what it should highlight.

Comment: Check the markdown for such things. The rendered view doesn't show HTML comments.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: Still, moderators have more important things to do than editing posts.